# How to create a textbox like Outlook To (names of the recipients) in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, html, css

I need to create a text box control like the **outlook To** .
Basically I need to enter some username separated by semicolon and Ctrl K(or button click) will validate that users just like in Outlook.

Can anyone helps here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Stackoverflow works when you show what you have tried with any specific errors.  This is not a place to ask for work to be done for you.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very quick and dirty example of what you might try, obviously there could be improvements made, but for the most part something like this would occur.

```js
// list of possible matches
var names = ['john', 'ben', 'dylan', 'kelly', 'beth']

// on form submission
$('form').on('submit', function(){
  // get the input
  var text = $('input[type=text]').val()
  var match = text;
  
  // check each name
  names.forEach(function(e,i){
    // check if the name matches
    if(e.indexOf(text) > -1) {
      // found a match, set it
      match = e
    }
  })
  // update the input
  $('input[type=text]').val(match)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="text">
  <input type="submit" value="Validate">
</form>
```